# api design in swift: supply default hashValue in a protocol?

Tags: swift, generics

Still learning Swift... when designing the class for a graph edge, I want to abstract and make it a protocol:

```
protocol GraphEdge: Hashable {
    typealias Vertex
    var v1: Vertex {get}
    var v2: Vertex {get}
}
```

(protocol cannot have generics, so I use associated types).
I want to provide a default `==` operator, so I implement it this way:

```
func ==<E: GraphEdge where E.Vertex: Equatable>(e1: E, e2: E) -> Bool {
    return e1.v1 == e2.v1 && e1.v2 == e2.v2
}
```

Is it correct (from a design point of view)?
How to implement in a similar manner a default `hashValue: Int` member?
It cannot be declared into the protocol itself...

In my current implementation, the class implementing the protocol has to implement `hashValue: Int` as well, but it leads to very repetitive code:

```
struct Edge<V: Hashable>: GraphEdge {
    let v1, v2: V
    var hashValue: Int {return v1.hashValue + v2.hashValue}
}

struct WeightedEdge<V: Hashable>: GraphEdge {
    let v1, v2: V
    let w: Float
    var hashValue: Int {return v1.hashValue + v2.hashValue}
}
```

Comment: Note that in Swift,  integer arithmetic overflow  causes a runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seem your Vertex type conforms to Hashable protocol, so you can do ..

```
protocol GraphEdge: Hashable {
    typealias Vertex: Hashable
    var v1: Vertex {get}
    var v2: Vertex {get}
}

extension GraphEdge {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return v1.hashValue + v2.hashValue
    }
}
```

just be careful, returning hasValue as a sum of hashValues of two Vertexes may not be the ideal solution

Comment: Was about to post the same solution :) – But you should combine the hash values with `^` or `&+` in order to avoid integer overflow.

Comment: @Martin R ha, i just edit my answer about hashVale :-). it looks like a race .... your note is very helpful for the guy!